# Computer freezes up

Tags: freeze, google-chrome

I am using the latest Ubuntu OS and up-to-date Chrome browser. Occasionally when I am working at a 5 hour stretch, the computer will freeze up completely and I will have to close down manually and reboot. When this happens I lose the material I have been working on as I cannot save it. And I often receive a notice at this time saying that my profile is not available or that I do not have a profile.

I am an Ubuntu user not a technician and do not know what to do about this problem.

Comment: would you provide more info about this non-available profile problem? a screenshot maybe

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: For anyone who currently has this problem (and maybe found this by searching): [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) If the whole system is freezing and programs other than Chrome aren't working, then something more is wrong than just with Chrome. (It's unclear to me if that's the case here--actually I think it is not--but it may be relevant to others who find this by searching.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in chrome to test this to see if chrome has a bug in it that is making it crash like that. You can use Firefox for a day to see if your system locks up or not if not then its chrome freezing up in which case you have a few choices .

- You can either use Firefox Until you get a update for chrome that may fix this issue
- Try to find another browser that will work Until a solution  for the system freezing up
- you can also try to uninstall chrome and reinstall  `sudo apt-get autoremove google-chrome`   reboot then  `sudo apt-get install google-chrome` might help if something in chrome got corrupted.

I understand that this isn't much of a fix more of a possible workaround